# Is it possible to invalidate a dispenser after it has been used once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am making a map in Minecraft that other people can play. I have a dispenser with an iron, golden and diamond sword in it. I want the player to be able to use this dispenser only once. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the switch also activate some water (a current passing glitched water will make it flow normally) to wash away part of the redstone, stopping further current.

Comment: Notch is in bug fixing mode, this glitch may be gone by the time 1.6 is released!

Comment: Well that'll ruin thousands of contraptions, I sure hope not...

Comment: He's already 'broken' minecart boosters and boat elevators, so beware!

Comment: This can be done with pistons now.

Answer (score 19):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to build an [RS-NOR latch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits#RS_NOR_latch), and wire the input and the dispenser to it. When you activate the input, the RS-NOR will flip, causing it to stay on. This means that no matter how many times you press the button, the dispenser will only dispense one time (unless of course you reset the latch).

---

This is an example of what the contraption may look like from the outside.

[image]

The following image is a look at the actual RS-NOR latch within the circuit. This is a vertical RS-NOR latch, because it only takes up one block wide of space (with the exception of the button, which isn't needed). When the button in the first image is pressed, it triggers the bottom redstone torch in this image to turn off, which then makes the wire running on the top of the latch turn off. The redstone torch on the left side of the latch turns on, giving continuous power the latch and not allowing subsequent button presses to do anything. While this is happening, it also powers the wiring extending downwards, which is wired to the dispenser.

The button pictured, however, acts as a reset switch, which is helpful when doing maintenance.

[image]

Finally, here is a broader look at the entire circuit.

[image]

Comment: Texture Pack? I like.

Comment: It's [ShortStuf7's Clean Design Pack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=99951).

Answer (score 15):

#### Simple:

Wire up switch to TNT to remove dispenser after use.

#### Better:

Use a [Latch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits#Latches_and_Flip-Flops). This way, the first time the switch is activated, it will activate the dispenser. Subsequent presses will not have any effect. This simplest way to do this is to connect the output of an OR gate to one of the inputs (the other input to the switch, and the dispenser also connected to the output). This way it will 'stick' on once activated, and further button presses will do nothing.

[image: Single use dispenser]

Comment: The dispenser spits out an item when I complete the circuit but pressing the pressure plate won't have any effect.

Comment: @Radek: there is a redstone torch attached to the upper stone block. It's kinda hard to see.

Comment: @Radek, @Javier I've uploaded a clearer pic.

Comment: May the problem be that my floor is sand instead of grass? Here is  a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ZnXgp.jpg

Comment: @Radek That circuit looks fine to me, sand won't make a difference. I've built a version with a reset switch - handy for testing: http://i.imgur.com/ir4Ov.png

Comment: Do you mind if I edit another design into your answer @fredley? I don't want to post it as another answer as it wouldn't really add any extra content.

Comment: @Kevin of course go ahead

Comment: On second thought, I decided to post an answer of my own and go really in-depth on how the RS-NOR actually works.

Comment: Won't this circuit reset when the chunk is reloaded?  The quester could leave the area (travel 4.5 chunks), come back, and get a second shot of getting a good sword.  Although I suppose that could be solvable by a one way steel door.

Comment: @MBraedley This is true of any redstone circuitry, one-way steel doors are essential!

Comment: @Radek Redstone circuitry is quirky in that _some_ circuits can behave slightly differently depending on how they're oriented (e.g. in the case of the [north/south quirk](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_circuits#The_North.2FSouth_Quirk). Maybe that's the case here. fredley's screenshot is taken facing northwards (i.e. the pillar he is standing on is south of the circuit), so try building it in that orientation. (You can tell the orientation by the "clump" found on the northwest corner of the grass tile)

Comment: The N/S quirk shouldn't be affecting this circuit, as it doesn't rely on tick-specific timings. More likely is that the pressure plate wasn't wired up correctly.